# Organize Firebase database for multiinstance app

Tags: firebase

I am new to firebase and i am testing if it is good for my next project.As simplified example of my project i will give a TODO list.I want different clients to login with email and password and after the login to gain access to their part of the database only.After that every client should be able to create users of their part of the  app with diferent privileges.As an example the client is a family.They use my todo app.The father have admin acces, the son can only read massages and so on.The other account is defferent familly and so on.So every account should have copy of the whole three of nodes.I should be something like multinstance application.The clients won't share any data so i do not think it will be good idea to put all similar data in one table.So i think abbout the shema :

```
    account1
        users
         user 1
           name : John
           type : Admin
         user 2
           name: Ben
           type: User
       todolist
          massages
            1
              author : John
            2
              author : Ben
       appsettings
            1
             some settings
...... more nodes


-----------------------------------

account2
     users
       user1
         name : Jen
         type : users
       user2
         name : Sam
      todolist
        massages
          1
            author : Jen
.....same tables like account1
```

Is this the right way to structure my database and what would be the proper way to orginize my login process? The account owner should login with email and password and after that every user should have some password to gain access based on his settings in the account - settings node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good question but there are a few items that should be addressed which will help clarify the question and answer.

Firebase does not have tables. It's a JSON data structure that has nodes; parents and children as such (and this is conceptual)

```
app_node
  parent_node_1
    child_node_1
      child_of_child_node_1
    child_node_2
      child_of_child_node_2
  parent_node_2
    child_node_1
    etc
```

What this means is that all of your app data exists in a single app node - so there is no choice other than to store all of your app data within that space. however, there are ways to make it keep that data 'separated'.

Assume for a moment that parent_node_1 was a_family and parent_node_2 was b_family.

The way to prevent a_family from accessing b_family data is through rules. You set up your rules so that users of a_family can only read/write data to the a_family node.

(conceptually)

```
.read
   authentication = true and this user is a member of a_family
.write
   authentication = true and this user is a member of a_family
```

In practice is would look something like:

```
"$user_id": {
  ".read": "auth != null && $user_id == auth.id && $user_id exists in node a_family/users"
```

Users can only read/write from nodes that belong to their family, so the path $user_id would be equal to their auth.id

There are challenges with the design of apps where you want to have totally separate spaces for your data but Firebase has some new tools available that make crafting rules for these situations 'easier'.

You should review the [Firebase Security and Rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/) section and special note on the Bolt Compiler info.

Comment: If I used SQL database I would build different database for every client.Lets imagine it will be some inventory management software or something.Every client is independent.In firebase world I imagine I could use different root nodes for every client and under this node there will be the child nodes needed for app to operate. Is this possible. I think I will try to build something and test but I need to hear some advice.I can have the id of the root for every client so they can use the app with addresses like this xxxxxx.firebaseapp.com/accoun1 under this root the structure is similar.

Comment: In SQL, you are correct. However this is NoSQL and therefore there isn't an option to have different root nodes for each client. As I mentioned in my answer, you can have your_app.firebase.com/account1 and your_app.firebase.com/account2 and then leverage rules to keep the users of account1 in the account1 node.

Comment: As a followup, I would encourage you to explore Firebase as it's abilities and performance work well for this kind of app. However, having discreet, separated data is not a strong point for Firebase so you have to code for it accordingly and lean on rules (heavily) to make it work. I have suggested to the Firebase team that offering some kind of group structure for users and data would really open Firebase up to a whole new realm of app development.